# Question from the 2016 junior mathematical games olympiad (of my country)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

Greetings to everyone on the forum :) I'm currently training for this year's mathematical games olympiad and stumbled across this question.

> Many two digit numbers can be written as a sum of two primes, find the two digit number that can be decomposed accordingly in the most different ways.

By bruteforce calculation you get the answer to be 90, but it's too unefficient considering the huge time pressure of these competitions. Anyone can help find a better strategy to solve this problem?

Sorry for any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Related: https://oeis.org/A061358

Comment: I can't imagine anything faster than brute force.  Given the large number of small primes, I would indeed expect the answer to be near $100$  and maybe one could argue that it is probably divisible by $3$ and $5$ (though those arguments are probably harder than the raw search).

Comment: There are some small tricks that can increase the speed of a brute force search: (1) check only evens. (2) search the primes above half the number being tested, not below, as there are fewer of them. (3) as lulu indicates, start at the top and go down - if you find a result with $k$ decompositions, you can automatically remove all numbers with fewer than $2k$ primes below them from your list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a graphical to the bruteforce method?

[image]

Write the odd numbers on two axis, mark the primes with horizontal and vertical lines.
In each diagonal (see the green line in the image) the sum of the values on the axis is the same.
Now we count in a diagonal how many intercections there are. In the example we start at 21+3=24. We find 6 intersections, but 3 are duplicates due to symmetry.
We can see that 24=5+19=7+17=11+13.

Not sure if they had a ruler, without it and doing in by hand might be very error prone. But with it, the approuch could be feasible

Comment: Slightly easier might be to use 2 strips of paper with 100 equal spacings, and the primes highlighted. Rotate one piece of paper and place it over the other, which gives us numbers that sum to $n$. The times when the highlighted numbers pair up is when we get 2 primes that sum to $n$. Then move that paper along and see how many such pairs we can get.